# How to prevent Images squeezed in Xamarin.Forms Button?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Button Images inside Xamarin.Forms are appearing squeezed on iOS. How do you set the Image to display in normal aspect ratio in XAML? Also as a bonus how do you make sure the Button Images line up vertically? I have tried setting the *WidthRequest* XAML property but it has no effect.

[image: Xamarin.Forms Button with Image]

XAML in ContentPage.Content:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="20">
    <Button Image="icon_facebook" Clicked="onClicked" Text="Facebook" />
    <Button Image="icon_twitter" Clicked="onClicked" Text="Twitter" />
    <Button Image="icon_microsoft" Clicked="onClicked" Text="Microsoft Account" />
    <Button Image="icon_google" Clicked="onClicked" Text="Google" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: They all seem similarly distorted, why not pre-size them with some blank padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to it you could use the `ImageButton` from the [XLabs package](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton).

Alternatively you could go for a `ListView` with `ImageCell`s or if that doesn't give you enough flexibility create your own `ViewCell`. These align well by default and you can trigger the proper action when a user taps an item in the list.

Here is an example of Apple themselves doing something similar:

[image: ListView button example]